# VBA Word error: Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm currently trying to write a script using VBA to generate a word document that has sections taken from a defined recordset in access.

However, I don't quite know how to input a field into the word vba and later reference it to data in access. Currently, I have the code below,

I managed to insert the field into the word automation, however, I get the error that the member does not exist at the rslet function.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim objWord As Word.Application 
Dim doc As Word.Document 
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
Dim db As Database 
Set db = CurrentDb 
Dim strsql As String 
strsql = "SELECT Function from Function" 
Dim rslet As DAO.RecordSet 
Set rslet = db.OpenRecordset(strsql)

With objWord .Visible = True 
Set doc = .Documents.Add 
doc.SaveAs CurrentProject.Path & "\TestDoc1.docx" 
End With

With objWord 
    .Selection.TypeText Text:="1.0 Introduction"
    .Selection.TypeParagraph 
    .Selection.TypeText Text:="1.3 Functions" 
    .Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range,
    Type:=wdFieldEmpty, 
    Text:="F", PreserveFormatting = FALSE 
    .Selection.TypeParagraph 
 With doc.FormFields("F").Result = rslet!Function 
   End With
 End With

doc.Save 
doc.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: `"SELECT Function from Function"` -- if this is even in parts actual code, it cannot work. You shouldn't use the same name for the table and a column, and `Function` is a reserved word. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words

Comment: @Andre I changed the field and table names that adopted the name Function, however, I still get the same error code.

Comment: Table and field having same name is possible (query works), just not sensible. Function being a reserved word would not cause issue in query. So why would code have issue with opening this recordset - especially after changing table and field names? Something else is going on. For a start, `.Visible = True` needs to be on another line. I copy/pasted your code. I have an error on the `Fields.Add` line - the code is red. Still investigating.

Comment: I am surprised code runs at all. `Fields.Add` code either needs line continuation character or don't wrap on multiple lines. Also missing `:` after `PreserveFormatting`.

Comment: Correction to comment, recordset opens but issue is on line that pulls value from recordset and tries to set Word form field. Not sure it causes problem but don't see need for `With End With` for the `.Result` line.

Comment: I tested code with above edits. Word doc is created but it displays text **Error! Bookmark not defined.** and Access triggers error message.

Comment: @June7 Apologies for all these issues, just started VBA yesterday for this program and honestly still trying to wrap my head around many things.
Although, if possible, could I just ask, is it actually possible to generate an instance of word report in access and also fill in certain sections with data from access all within a single sub?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but complicated. Why using Word and not Access report?

Comment: @June7 Is it possible to replicate a near 30 page word report in access? The word report really is more of a word document for reading purposes rather than a data-focused report.

Comment: Yes, that is also possible although not with the same formatting capabilities. Sounds like a lot of 'boiler plate' static text. Probably should create a Word template document with bookmarks/formfields and then VBA can manage the data fill-in, essentially automating a "mail merge". If you want to display table structures in Word, that gets even more complicated. I've never needed any of this myself, just helped a few forum posters with their requirements.

Comment: @June7 I am currently trying to fill it in with bookmarks, but quite a number of hiccups too.  There is a section where it adopts a word table, so not exactly your standard clean data table. The issue is that I want to create a new instance of that table for each record, but right now, however, the records for each bookmark seem to connect with each other in the same line. 
Also, on the word generation issue, as the local computers would change, it would be easier to generate the word, rather than have ppl tinker with the code as the file would not be on a network file.

Comment: @June7 additionally, this might be a bit much, but would it be possible to pm you via some medium for some further help?

Comment: Communication only through forum postings. Might want to try another forum that has a more 'discussion' oriented format rather than the Q&A setup of SO. Word automation is a fairly common topic. Don't really understand the 'have ppl tinker with the code' comment - why would people tinker with code?

Comment: @June7 ah i understand thanks. Oh as I probably would not have a network folder shared by everyone, users would probably save the word template in different folders. Wouldn't this mean that for each user on their own local device, they would have to edit the filepath of the word in the access vba?

Comment: Would have to provide a way for user to select file and path and use that selection in code. That's what Windows FileSystemObject automation is for - another topic for you to research. Or make sure the Word doc is filed in same folder as the Access file so `CurrentProject.Path` will work.

Comment: @June7 sounds great, will dive into that filesystemobject you're talking about. Do you mind going indepth about the currentproject.path? let's assume that I provide the word and access all in a single folder, currently, im using w.app.documents.open("filepath").
is it that they have to open the word template, and use Application.CurrentProject.Path

Comment: Continued discussion is not appropriate for SO. Prolonged discussion is not what comments are for. Comments are not for Q&A. This is not appropriate venue for in-depth tutoring. I am surprised SO has not yet prompted us to go to chat window. I have directed you to possible cause of error with posted code and approaches to explore. You need to do research and revise code. Edit question or start a new one. Or visit another forum. Can use CurrentProject.Path to build the "filepath" input for Open method.